# How to disable a CodedUI Test Agent from code?

Tags: tfs, error-handling, automation, coded-ui-tests

We have a service to pick up custom tests in XML and convert those to CodedUI tests. We then start a process for MSTest to load the tests into the Test Controller which then distributes the tests across various Agents. We run regression tests at night, so no one is around to fix a system if something goes wrong. When certain exceptions occur in the test program, it pops open an error window and no more test can run on the system. Subsequent tests are loaded into the agent and fail immediately because they can not perform their assigned tasks. Thousands of tests that should take all night on multiple systems now fail in minutes.

We can detect that an error occurred by how quickly a test is returned, but we don't know how to disable the agent so as not to allow it to pick up any more tests.

**addendum:**

If the test has failed so miserably that no more tests can attempt a successful run (as noted, we may not have an action to handle some, likely new, popup), then we want to disable that agent as no more tests need to run on it: they will all fail. As we have many agents running concurrently, if one fails (and gets disabled), the load can still be distributed without a long string of failures. These other regression tests can still have a chance to succeed (everything works) or fail (did we miss another popup, or is this an actual regression failure).

2000 failures in 20 seconds doesn't say anything except 1 system had an problem that no one realized it would have and now we wasted a whole night of tests. 2 failures (1 natural, 1 caused by issue from previous failure) and 1 system down means the total nights run might be extended by an hour or two and we have useful data on how to start the day: fix 1 test and rerun both failures.

Comment: If no-one is around to fix it... why does it matter that the consequenting test fail ? If the run was

Answer (score 0):

One would need to abort the testrun in that case. If you are running mstest yourself, you would need to inject a ^c into the command line process. But: if no-one is around to fix it, why does it matter that the consequenting test fail ? if its just to see which test was the cause of the error quickly, why not generate a code ui check to see if the message box is there and mark the test inconclusive with Assert.inconclusive. The causing test would stand out like a flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect the point at which you want to disable the agent then you can disable the agent by running the "TestAgentConfig.exe delete" which will reset the agent to unconfigured state.